# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) during ajax POST in Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, cookies, django-templates

i am trying to send a csv file and bunch of data through ajax getting Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) error while sending csrftoken one more thing ,i checked i am getting different token in code and cookies so i tried.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/ docs as well but no luck 
could you please help me out here ,

**here is js code**

```
$('#upload').click(function(){
    console.log('hello');
    var store = $('#id_store').val();
    var kitchen = $('#id_kitchen').val();
    var form = $('.csv').prop('files')[0];
    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    console.log(store)
    data={
     'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken,
     'kitchen':kitchen,
     'store':store,
     'csv_file':form,
     }
    console.log(data)
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{url('custom-admin:csv_upload')}}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
         processData: false,
         contentType:false,
         success: function (data) {
           if(data.status){
            alert(data.message)
           }
           else{alert(data.message)}
    }
    });
    })
```

**html File**

```
   <form id="demo-form2" method="post" data-parsley-validate="" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-5"> Store <span
         class="required">*</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 stores" id="stores">
         {{ form.store }}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-5"> Kitchen <span
         class="required">*</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 kitchen_list" id="kitchen_list">
         {{ form.kitchen }}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group"  >
      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-5" >  Upload File <span
         class="required"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 file">
         {{form.csv_file}}
         {% if form_errors.csv_file %}
         <div class="alert alert-danger">{{form_errors.csv_file}}</div>
         {% endif %}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group" >
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
         <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary upload" id="upload"> Upload </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class CsvImportForm(forms.Form):
    kitchen = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            'type': "radio",
            'class': "btn btn-primary btn-md",
            'data-parsley-multiple': 'gender'
        })
    )

    store = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            'type': "radio",
            'class': "btn btn-primary btn-md stores",
            'data-parsley-multiple': 'gender'
        })
    )
    csv_file = forms.FileField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
            'type': "file",
            'class':"csv",
            "data-validation": "mime",
            'data-validation-allowing': "csv",
            'data-validation-error-msg-mime': "You can only upload images in (csv)."
        })
    )
```

Comment: When you say you had no luck when you tried what is in the Django docs, do you mean you still get the CSRF token missing error? It is a bit unclear in your question

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: @DanielHolmes yeah

Comment: @Mathyou I added JS code as wel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try with `javascript`'s  [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) function.

```
$('#upload').click(function(){  
        var formData = new FormData();
        var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
        formData.append('store', $('#id_store').val());
        formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken);
        formData.append('kitchen',  $('#id_kitchen').val());
        formData.append('csv_file', $('.csv')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{url('custom-admin:csv_upload')}}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType:false,
        success: function (data) {
           if(data.status){
            alert(data.message)
           }
           else{
            alert(data.message)
           }
        }
    });
});
```